# Response for Indexing solr automatically

Tags: java

I have written a code for indexing the data into solr automatically. Request is send to solr for indexing the data. If data is large indexing takes time. I have to run search query on solr. How I can stop to run further java code till indexing is completed

Comment: Please consider including your code to allow for a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indexing data from a Database you can use DataImportHandler. It also comes with a scheduler called DataImportScheduler. You can configure the scheduler to run daily, hourly, or even after few minutes.

Solr can handle incoming search request during index updates. Your search requests will be contentiously served by Solr no matter the indexing is happening or not.